# Flurry not sending events to server till application restart

Tags: android, flurry

I have implemented Flurry in my Android app.It sends events to the flurry server but only when the application is started second time. For eg: if user  used the app on 1st September and again used it on 1st October then the stats of 1st September will be sent on 1st October,but i want events to be available after the app closes or in the real-time.

Here is My code:

```
package com.example.flurry;

import com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class Flurry extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_flurry);

        FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true);

        FlurryAgent.init(getBaseContext(), "FS3C2XNX8HRPD6GDJ7C2");

        Button check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FlurryAgent.logEvent("check button pressed");

                // Perform action on click
            }
        });

        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FlurryAgent.logEvent("stop button pressed");


            }
        });


    }



    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
       super.onStart();
       FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true);
       FlurryAgent.setLogEvents(true);
       FlurryAgent.setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE);
       FlurryAgent.onStartSession(getBaseContext(), "FS3C2***************");
       // your code
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop()
    {
       super.onStop();
       FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
       // your code
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.flurry, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

When I restart the app in logcat following line comes:

```
09-02 10:28:31.817: W/FlurryAgent(5684): Analytics report sent.
```

How can I send event data to the server in real-time or at application exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the **onStop** and **onStart** functions as these are deprecated in the latest flurry SDK and don't directly close the app.press the home button before closing the application. It will work